# Python Divide By Zero Error

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

I have a Class in python, with the following attributes:

> ```
>     self.number1 = 0
>     self.number2 = 0
>     self.divided = self.number1/self.number2
> ```

This of course throws up the zero error:

> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

The idea is that I will increment number1 and number2 later on, but will self.divided be automatically updated? If it is auto updated then how do I get around the zero error? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, `self.divided` is a simple attribute and will not automatically update. For dynamic attributes, use a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) instead:

```
class Foo(object):
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0

    @property
    def divided(self):
        return self.number1 / self.number2
```

Comment: You could also use the shorter version `divided = property(lambda obj: obj.number1 / obj.number2)`

Comment: @Fabian: and then I have to explain lambdas too. Let's keep this simple. :-)

Comment: now you could argue that you have to explain decorators too :-)

Comment: @Fabian: let's hope the OP has the nouse to read the linked documentation then!

Comment: @dedoco: Of course it does. What do you want it to do? Return 42?

Comment: Probably the program is not supposed to resolve the question of what is the answer to life the universe and everything, but if you look at the actual question, there is written `If it is auto updated then how do I get around the zero error?` This kinda indicates that one would want to get around the zero error, doesn't it?

Comment: @dedoco: The OP hoped `self.divided` would later on magically become equal to the division of `number1` and `number2`, if only the `ZeroDivisionError` could be solved for now. It was only the `ZeroDivisionError` the OP thought was preventing the scheme from working in the first place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: which was a wrong assumption since `self.divided` is not automatically updated, I completely agree with you. Defining divided as a property allows to automatically update it, but the `ZeroDivisionError`, that obviously occurred before, will still occur and potentially prevent the script form running smoothly.

Comment: @dedoco: perhaps, but that's still a separate issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree. But this issue is addressed in the second question statement of the OP.

Answer (score 16):

Automatic update with avoidance of ZeroDivisionError:

```
@property
def divided(self):
    try:
        #suppose that number2 is a float
        return self.number1/self.number2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following in single as I have shown:

```
self.divided = self.number1/(self.number2  or not self.number2)
```

this ensures that if your value is 0, you don't get the error.
But be sure, use this only if you are using integer values or values which are greater than 1.

Comment: Very hacky, but nice!