# why can't I add 2 columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns in excel. I get an error from simply dividing them with pandas. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('day.xlsx', sheet_name = 'day1')
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df=df.rename(columns={0: 'Time', 'null': 'Temp', 'null.1':'Pressure'})
df['ratio']=df['Temp']/df['Pressure']
```

I am trying to create a third column 'ratio' from dividing 'Temp' with 'Pressure'.

Error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Are you getting the divide by zero error? [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646347/python-divide-by-zero-error)

Comment: Ensure that the columns 'Temp' and 'Pressure' are in numerical data type while importing and also make sure that none of the values in 'Pressure' is 0 or null.

Comment: my error message:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: yes I do have null values but am I would prefer not to remove them

Comment: Can cross check the types of Temp Column and Pressure column?

Comment: try to do `df['ratio'] = df['Temp*].astype(float)/df['Pressure'].astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explicit:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'

It means that in `df['Temp']/df['Pressure']` some (or all) of the values of `df['Pressure']` are strings. You must first convert them to float, normally with `astype(float)` if all values represent acceptable float values or with `to_numeric(coerce=True)` if you want to be super safe: any non convertible string will be changed to `NaN`:

```
df['ratio']=df['Temp']/pd.to_numeric(df['Pressure'], coerce=True)
```

If you still get errors `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'`, you will have to do the same conversion on `df['Temp']`.